# Deleting a targeted row in function component React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to render a list of rows that can be added to and deleted dynamically. I have 2 components that handle adding and removing rows: `ClassComponent` and `FunctionComponent`. `ClassComponent` works as intended, but `FunctionComponent` only deletes the first row. The rows are stored as state and are updated using setState(). How can I make `FunctionComponent` logically equivalent to `ClassComponent`?

I'm using the library `uuid` to create unique keys.

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ClassComponent />
      <FunctionComponent />
    </div>
  );
}

class ClassComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    list: [{ id: uuidv4() }, { id: uuidv4() }],
  };

  handleDelete = (id) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      list: prevState.list.filter((row) => row.id !== id),
    }));
  };

  handleAdd = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      list: [...prevState.list, { id: uuidv4() }],
    }));
  };

  render() {
    const { list } = this.state;

    return (
      <>
        <ul>
          {list.map(({ id }) => (
            <Row key={id} id={id} onClick={this.handleDelete}>
              {id}
            </Row>
          ))}
        </ul>
        <button onClick={this.handleAdd}>Add</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}

const FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState([{ id: uuidv4() }, { id: uuidv4() }]);

  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
    const copy = list.slice();
    copy.splice(id, 1);
    setList(copy);
  };

  const handleAdd = () => {
    setList([...list, { id: uuidv4() }]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {list.map(({ id }) => (
          <Row key={id} id={id} onClick={handleDelete}>
            {id}
          </Row>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <button onClick={handleAdd}>Add</button>
    </>
  );
};

const Row = ({ onClick, children, id }) => (
  <li>
    {children} <button onClick={() => onClick(id)}>Delete</button>
  </li>
);
```

Comment: It is "function" component not "functional"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason not to use `array.prototype.filter()` just like you've done in your Class Component? This seems more readable and ensures you avoid mutating state directly in fewer steps.

Here is what that would look like in your `handleDelete` function in `FunctionComponent`:

```
const handleDelete = (id) => {
  setList(list.filter((row) => (
    row.id !== id
  )));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `FunctionalComponent` you need to give index of the entry to `splice` method. Try like below.

```
  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    const copy = list.slice();
    // find the index
    const index = copy.findIndex(({ id: ID }) => id === ID);
    // do the deletiong using that index
    copy.splice(index, 1);
    setList(copy);
  };
```

[image: Edit nifty-shannon-cv0k2u]

Answer (score 0):

You have to review your usage of the `splice` Array prototype.

```
copy.splice(id, 1);
```

Splice need to be passed as first argument an index and at second argument a delete count as such:

```
splice(start, deleteCount)
```

and you are passing an id to it. Actually in your case you are passing undefined as you're calling the function without argument.
I guess you could use the index of the map function to make it work:

```
    {list.map(({ id }, index) => (
      <Row key={id} id={id} onClick={() => handleDelete(index)}>
        {id}
      </Row>
    ))}
```

In your case you were passing undefined as id and 1 as the deleteCount so it was always deleting the first item.

Answer (score 0):

in the functional component, you did not pass the id!

```
const FunctionalComponent = () => {
const [list, setList] = useState([{ id: uuidv4() }, { id: uuidv4() }]);

const handleDelete = (id) => {
// get all object except the id
const newRows = list.filter((i) => i.id !== id);
setList(newRows);
};

 const handleAdd = () => {
   setList([...list, { id: uuidv4() }]);
 };

 return (
    <>
    <ul>
    {list.map(({ id }) => (
      <Row key={id} id={id} onClick={() => handleDelete(id)}>
        {id}
      </Row>
    ))}
  </ul>
  <button onClick={handleAdd}>Add</button>
  </>
 );
 };
```